# Why is some time series models(ARIMA,BATS,ETS) generate flat lines for forecasts?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

what is the reason behind flat line generation for some time series models ? Is it because they assume constant trend for forecast ? Please help be with a logical reasoning , i have read some materials online but couldn't be convinced

Thanks

Comment: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/flat-forecasts/

Comment: Thanks Prof. Can you help in answering this question about forecast package ?
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/431848/how-does-bats-model-work